# Getting text linked to comment

Tags: vba, ms-word

I already have the following code to export all comments to another MSWord file.

```
Sub exportcomments()
Dim s As String
Dim cmt As Word.Comment
Dim doc As Word.Document
For Each cmt In ActiveDocument.Comments
s = s & cmt.Initial & cmt.Index & "," & cmt.Range.Text & vbCr
Next
Set doc = Documents.Add
doc.Range.Text = s
End Sub
```

However, I need to have the highlighted text of each comment to be printed alongside each comment in the new MSWord file.

PS. I am a total newbie to vba. I only got the code to do this. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
s = s & cmt.Initial & cmt.Index & "," & cmt.Range.Text & vbCr
```

to something like:

```
s = s & cmt.Scope.Text & vbTab & cmt.Initial & cmt.Index & "," & cmt.Range.Text & vbCr
```

Comment: cmt.Reference.Text is empty or better still, it shows nothing, empty spaces

Comment: Oops - should have used cmt.Scope.Text. See updated answer